# Do block returning user and not collaborators

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm needing some help with a do block that is returning the wrong generated link. I know it's a simple fix but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am building an app clone of Wikipedia where there are wikis, users, and now collaborators. This clone is for a project tutorial but the specific step of implementing collaborators into the view is confusing me. With the code posted below, I'm getting a generated link on my user#show of the current user. **What I really need is a list of wikis where the current user is the collaborator.**

Let me know if any other code is needed to assist with the fix and thank you in advance for any help.

**User Show View**

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <% @collaborator.each do |collaborator| %>
        <div class="row">
          <ul>
            <li><%= link_to collaborator %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**User Controller**

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @wikis = @user.wikis
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    @collaborators = Collaborator.all
    @collaborator = @wiki.collaborators.find_by(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wikis
  has_many :collaborators
  has_many :collaborating_wikis, through: :collaborators, foreign_key: "wiki_id", class_name: "Wiki"
  validates :wiki_id, presence: true
end
```

**Wiki Model**

```
class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :collaborators
  has_many :users, through: :collaborators
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**Collaborator Model**

```
class Collaborator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wiki
  validates :wiki_id, :user_id, presence: true
  validates :wiki_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:wiki_id, :user_id] }
end
```

Comment: Hi Tucker, it would be really useful to have a link to the github repo so I can clone down the repo and have a play.

Comment: Your code above is doing an `each` loop on `@collaborator`, not `@collaborators`.

Answer (score 0):

What you say in the bold text and the bit before the bold text seem contradictory to me, but (without being able to clone down your code and play with it) to retrieve a collection of wikis where the collaborator is the current user, I suspect what you need is:

Controller:
`@collaborating_wikis = current_user.collaborating_wikis`

And in your view:

```
<% @collaborating_wikis.each do |collaborating_wiki| %>
  <%= link_to "Wiki", wiki_path(collaborating_wiki) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I added the code you provided and I got this error message: `Could not find the source association(s) "collaborating_wiki" or :collaborating_wikis in model Collaborator. Try 'has_many :collaborating_wikis, :through => :collaborators, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or wiki?`. I have the `has_many` association in my user model so I'm confused on why I'm getting this now. Here is the github repo just in case: https://github.com/tuckermullen/blocipedia and thanks a lot for the help btw!

Comment: Which branch? I've cloned down the master but Collaborator model isn't there. Btw do your tests run for you?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that...it's the collaborator branch.

Comment: Do your tests run for you? And are you able to 'Sign Up' when running your project locally?

Comment: I haven't added any tests yet. I am able to sign up, sign in/out, I simply just can't get the user#show page to show the specific wikis in which he/she is a collaborator.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error when signing up (same error when trying to create a User in the rails console, too.

Comment: Hmmm...that is weird, in the mean time use the following to sign in. Email: mullentucker@gmail.com with password = password.

Comment: I'm running locally (on my laptop), so I don't have access to the database on your hard drive :-)

Comment: Duh....sorry I am new. Well thanks a lot for your help...I'll keep trying and see if I can iron it out.

Comment: Are you sure you have your present code pushed to github? I had to remove the `validates :wiki_id, presence: true` from the User model to be able to create a User - I'm not sure it's possible to create a User otherwise, since you also have the Wiki model validating for the presence of user_id - they're both validating for the presence of each other's id, but you can't create both at the same time!

Comment: Ok I'm giving up for now, but my advice is to edit your original question and update it with an explanation of how you want your app to be structured i.e. how should Users relate to Wikis; what is a Collaborator; how should a Collaborator relate to Wikis and Users? This information is important to be able to understand the intention behind pieces of the code and for others to help you sort this out. I might check back in a couple of days to see if you've done that :-) Good luck - I started with Ruby and Rails and now I'm a pro developer! (Just not that great a developer yet!)